# Add a line from infobox to the marker API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infobox

I've created map with custom .gif image in place of markers.  Then created a info box which must sit some way from the image.  There will be several images each with an infobox.  What I seek to do is add a line from the infobox to the image so when the screen gets cluttered it is obvious which infobox balongs to which image.
The line drawn between two lat/lng points is no good as the infobox is diplayed in pixels, not lat/lng, and such a line is not related to the infobox so would not hide / visible as the infobox does.
Is this possible?
I using infobox.js
This is my code for the infobox.

```
infobox = new InfoBox({
     content: document.getElementById("infobox1"),
     disableAutoPan: false,
     maxWidth: 200,
     pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -150),
     zIndex: null,
     boxStyle: {
        width: "150px"
    },
    closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
    closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
});
infobox.open(map, marker);
```

Code works. I show it in case it has bearing on what I want to do.

This is my div.

```
<div id='infobox-wrapper'>
  <div id='infobox1'> this is text text</div>
</div>
```

Found solution with this css

```
.infoBox:before{
 content : " ";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 1px solid transparent;
 border-right: 1px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 70px solid #000;
 position:absolute;
 top:-80px;
 left:130px;
}
```

Comment: As soon as I clicked I had a thought, and found the solution with this bit of css

Comment: .infoBox:before{
      content : " ";
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 1px solid transparent;
      border-right: 1px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 70px solid #000;
      position:absolute;
      top:-80px;
      left:130px;
    }